# Backing up a server to another server every night

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, mirroring

My company just set up an Amazon EC2 instance running Windows Server 2008 R2, and though we were planning on using that server as our main server, we have decided instead to use it as a backup for our current server.

The plan is to have the current server's files backed up to the cloud server every night. Of course performing a full backup at first, and then ultimately we would like to back up the files that have been modified every day automatically every night.

I was wondering if there was a simple way to do this, or if there is a third party application that can help with it.

**To Recap:**
We have two servers, and want to perform a backup of one onto the other every night. Just of the files modified each day if that is possible.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going from Windows to Windows, the built in Windows Backup is actually pretty good! It does "just work". [Here is an overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770266%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) of what it is and how to enable the role, and [here is a guide on how to set up the backup jobs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/404a51b5-99a6-43d1-b5a5-36261cb5ade2).

Of course this will rely on an open network between the 2 servers that you trust, as it works over SMB. This could be done with a VPN, but I wouldn't trust it in a simple 2 server setup over the internet like you describe.

Failing that I'd suggest using [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp). It's pretty simple and uses a client/server model. [The manual](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cts=1331587955196&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http://www.aboutmyip.com/files/DeltaCopyManual.pdf&ei=bmteT_ueJsPA0QXy3ejIDQ&usg=AFQjCNHd4qm6ckg2a-SrlWwJXt95nImz-g&sig2=QFMeGISQCi0d9UBCQAPYtQ) has an example in it of how to do a nightly backup.

Answer (score 2):

Generically, RSync (or the Windows variant, [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp))

Answer (score 0):

Besides rsync, you can use Bacula for this, but it might be overkill for your project. See: http://www.bacula.org/5.2.x-manuals/en/main/main/Enterprise_Bacula_New_Featu.html#SECTION00350000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

What about HP Storage Mirroring ? It is a great tool to address your problem.
It has real time replication, automatic failover and some other cool features.

Comment: http://h18006.www1.hp.com/products/storage/software/sm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

are you worried about archive copies of your data? If not, robocopy is tried, true and simple.

Here is an example:  Source = C:\source Destination = E:\Destination

```
robocopy c:\source e:\destination /mir /r:1 /w:1
```

If you want permissions captured there as well, then throw the `/copyall`  You can also copy to/from network shares as well, no need for a mapped drive.

This command will mirror the source directory, file/folder changes, delete's creates, etc are all mirrored.

If you need historical copies of your backups kept, then I would go with a traditional windows backup as reccomended by Simon.